# RecyclerView Items Clickable but invisble on some of huawei devices

Tags: java, xml, android-tabs

**I am facing a weird problem in my application some of Huawei users complain about white screen:**

This is an example of Huawei MediaPad T3 recycler view items not visible but when I click on the white space onClickListener fired

[image: This is an example of Huawei MediaPad T3 recycler view items not visible but when I click on the white space onClickListener fired]

[image: Any device, not Huawei recycler view working fine]

Any device, not Huawei recycler view working fine

Could anyone give me a hint for why this problem happens? , the same code works fine on all devices except Huawei

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, also for simple views. Did you solve it?

Comment: @leon yeah the problem was in this attribute 
 android:rotationY="180" 
remove it from your view in xml

Idk why it happens either but I'm guessing it had to do with EMUI